# Erratic behavior from ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenustrip

I am getting some erratic behavior from a `ContextMenuStip`:

```
 private void lstModules_MouseMove(object sender , MouseEventArgs e)
 { mouse = e.Location; }
 private void lstModules_MouseDown(object sender , MouseEventArgs e)
 {
  ListViewItem item = null;
  if((hitTest = lstModules.HitTest(mouse)) != null)
   item = hitTest.Item;

  switch (e.Button)
  {
   case MouseButtons.Right:
    if (item != null)
    {
     // valid item selection
     ShowModuleDetails(item.Name);
     lstModules.ContextMenuStrip = mnuContext_Module;
    }
    else
    {
     // right-click - no item selection
     lblModuleDetails.Text = string.Empty;
     lstModules.ContextMenuStrip = mnuContext_Desktop;
    }

    lstModules.ContextMenuStrip.Show(lstModules , mouse);
    break;
   case MouseButtons.Left:
    if (item != null)
    { ShowModuleDetails(item.Name); }
    break;
  }
 }
 private void ShowModuleDetails(string modName)
 {
        //  get module details from dictionary
  lblModuleDetails.Text = Modules[modName].Details;
 }
```

1. The item in the list view is not properly selected when the context menu is showing. In other words, when the item is selected, a detail string value is displayed in a label control.
2. If a context menu is visible, and an item is selected, the item details do not change.
3. Context menu location briefly appears at the *old* mouse location then moves to the *new* mouse location.

Is there something I'm doing wrong with the context menus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem as far as I could. I think I can help you out with at least two of the three issues you've listed.

> ***1. The item in the list view is not always properly selected. In other words, when the item is selected, a detail string value is displayed in a label control.***

You can be notified when an item has been selected via the `ListView.ItemSelectionChanged` event:

```
//
// this handler's only responsibility is updating the item info label:
//
void lstModules_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender,
                                     ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.IsSelected)
    {
        // an item has been selected; update the label, e.g.:
        lblModuleDetails.Text = e.Item.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        // some item has been de-selected; clear the label:
        lblModuleDetails.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

> ***3. Context menu location briefly appears at the old mouse location then moves to the new mouse location.***

I believe you try to do too much. Let the framework handle the displaying of the context menu which you have specified via the `ListView.ContextMenuStrip` property. The effect you experience is caused by your manually calling `ContextMenuStrip.Show(...)`, which results in the displaying of the context menu by the framework, and then you doing the same thing a second time, at another location.

Therefore, try not to call this function; the context menu should still appear.

```
//
// this handler's only responsibility is setting the correct context menu:
//
void lstModules_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        var hitTest = lstModules.HitTest(e.Location);
        if (hitTest != null && hitTest.Item != null)
        {
            lstModules.ContextMenuStrip = mnuContext_Module;
        }
        else
        {
            lstModules.ContextMenuStrip = mnuContext_Desktop;
        }
    }
}
```

Btw., if that works, you can also get rid of your `lstModules_MouseMove` event handler and the `mouse` location object.

Comment: Clearly, you are a genius. I guess I couldn't see the forest for the trees in this case...thx!!!