# How to get the explorer right click menu in Winforms ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, explorer

I am using a Winforms ListView to show some files, but other than showing the files like explorer does, I want to have the same explorer right click menu when you get when you right click an item inside.

Is this possible? How do I enable it for my ListView app?

Comment: are you wanting **the** explorer menu or an *explorer-like* context menu. And what code do you have in your listview now? I've just done some contextmenu stuff in a listview.

Comment: Thanks, I mean the explorer context menu that shows up based on whichever files you right click. Right now the code I have show populates the listview with items, but no right click menus yet.

Comment: Also consider using shell controls lie Shell MegaPack - http://www.ssware.com/megapack.htm - these are Explorer like controls with context menus, drag-drop, renaming, thumbnail view, detail view, etc, like Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of to do this is to use pinvoke and COM to do it.  The unmanaged API you want, I think, is [SHCreateDefaultContextMenu()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762127(VS.85).aspx).  Once you get the interop done (check pinvoke.net first), you can do the interop for all the other things required by [DEFCONTEXTMENU](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773251(VS.85).aspx).  It won't be easy.  Welcome to the land of PIDLs.

Comment: Thanks hope I can find my way from it.

Comment: I looked at pinvoke but these don't seem to be there. I can't be the first person who wanted this behaviour, right?

Comment: You can be the first person who bothers to share it with others.  There is a lot of obvious stuff missing from there.

Answer (score 2):

I was actually having trouble getting a custom context menu to show with a right click: [Erratic Behavior from ContextMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212705/erratic-behavior-from-contextmenustrip/2213009#2213009)

I still implemented slightly different:

```
    private void lstModules_MouseDown(object sender , MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        hitTest = lstModules.HitTest(e.Location);

        switch (e.Button)
        {
            case MouseButtons.Right:
                if (hitTest != null && hitTest.Item != null)
                {
                    // right clicking an item in the listview
                    selectedModule = hitTest.Item.Name;

                    lstModules.ContextMenuStrip = mnuContext_OptionsA;
                }
                else
                { 
                    // right clicking in white area of listview
                    lstModules.ContextMenuStrip = mnuContext_OptionsB; 
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need the [IContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776095%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface. Also see [this very useful series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/20/231739.aspx).